# Increase in server node instances doesn't improve throughput of an application

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, load-testing, rancher

We are using K8s and Rancher to deploy our java based microservices and using JMeter to perform load testing.

1): When we run load test on one of the micro service even with very simple controller method which just accepts the request and sends a response.
[image]
The micro service shows throughput as 90requests/sec - Means 90 requests are served per second.

2): Even after increasing the instances of the same microservices throughput of the load test we do doesn't increase a bit.
Means even through there are two instances of same micro service which are up and running and both are responding to the requests fired by JMeter. Still throughput remains same i.e 90 requests/second.

We tried finding out whether both services of the micro service are responding to the load test we are doing and came to know that both the services are doing there job correctly. Means both respond to the requests fired from JMeter, But still throughput remains same.

As per my understanding of Horizontal scale when one service is having throughput of 90requests/sec then when we have two services then throughput should scale up ( at least it will double i.e it should be 180requests/sec )

Note: We also tried to load testing from different systems ( Means me and my colleague did load testing from our systems but the combined throughput is 90requests/sec i.e 45 + 45 = 90 )

Comment: How are you running the load test?  (Is JMeter running in another Pod, outside the cluster via a load balancer, `kubectl port-forward`, something else?)  Does the application depend on an external resource like a database, or another service to render the PNG file you show in the question?  Have you checked that the HPA is actually provisioning more replicas of your Deployment?